# Mongoid: Retrieving objects in the order of the

Tags: mongoid

Suppose:

> mentions=["2","1","3"]
>
> unranked = User.where(:nickname.in => mentions).map

The output does not match the ordering in the provided array

> output is random => 3, 1, 2
>
> i want it as per the original array => 2, 1, 3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it like this:

```
mentions=["foo","bar","baz"]

ranked = User.where(:nickname.in => mentions).sort do |a, b|
  mentions.index(a.nickname) <=> mentions.index(b.nickname)
end
```

Not really the most elegant solution since I'm sorting in the application and not on the database engine but hey.. it works (*on small lists*).